# Why does a node in a TreePanel not show a load icon after I replaced the default icons?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I replaced the default icons of tree-nodes in my TreeStore:

```
  listeners: {
     append: function( oParentNode, oAppendedNode ) {
        oAppendedNode.set( 'icon', Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL );
     }
  }
```

But now they don't show the loading icon anymore.
Is there any simple way to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `icon` property was not set in the first place and the new one would override all icons (folder, file AND load) so I build 2 handlers, which remove the property while loading and add it back afterwards.

```
append: function( oParentNode, oAppendedNode ) {
  oAppendedNode.set( 'icon', Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL );

  oAppendedNode.on( 'beforeexpand', function() {
    oAppendedNode.set( 'icon', null );
  } );

  oAppendedNode.on( 'expand', function() {
    oAppendedNode.set( 'icon', Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL );
  } );
}
```